# Google Ad Manager - DFP : Can I serve multiple sizes from single Google DFP GPT ad slot?

Tags: html, adsense, google-dfp, google-ad-manager, google-publisher-tag

I am trying to understand how to implement DFP ad slots and call them on my page.
Firstly I want to clear one point that Google DFP [reference](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.displaydivorslot) says that each ad slot can be called only once per page however it does not say that if the ad slot as whole is allowed to call once per page or ad slot with size specific i.e. `/networkID/gptAdSlot (728x90)` once per page as well as `/networkID/gptAdSlot (300x250)` once per page?

If one adslot is allowed to call once per page, then possibly i have to create multiple ad slots for multiple sizes for same web page and I am trying to avoid that, instead what i am trying to do is I want to use one ad slot for one page but certainly my page will not have one size ad in one location. My page will have multiple sized ads across the location.

Thus I am confused on how to call structure this? will one ad slot can cater multiple sizes in the same page? or will i need multiple ad slots for multiple size ads in same page?

Another question is if a gpt adSlot supports multiple size, then can it serve all the sizes irrespective of series like 970x90 and 300x600? Or does it needs to be setup in a way that an ad slot can serve multiple sizes only if it falls in same series i.e. ad slots serving 300x250 can serve 300x600 as well as any smaller size that falls within the maximum size (H x W) mentioned?

Considering the fact the `<div>` that we will on the body will have a fixed size and therefore I expect the gpt to serve the creative according to the div sizes in entire page which will ensure that single gpt ad slot can serve multiple sized creatives in respective `<div>`'s according to the sizes when matched.

*its worth mentioning that none of the `<div>` will call sizes that will not be present in gpt ad slot's.

Let me know as I am badly stuck.

Comment: You should look at this sample and try : https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/ad-sizes. Take also a look at the sizeMapping reference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this resource, I've been through it and understood. what I can't understand here is that it says one ad slot can be called only once per page, so does that also limits sizes? I mean one ad slot for one size can be called once? or the one ad slot with multiple sizes can also be called in same page?

Comment: If my page has 3 ad placement  728x90, 300x250, 300x600. Can I call all the three sizes with one ad slot i.e: `/network_id/ad_slot`
or do I need to create child units like `/network_id/ad_slot/300x250` `/network_id/ad_slot/728x90` etc and so on?

Comment: Each defined slot is related to a specific div id in your DOM. Each slot can have one or multiple sizes declared. You can share the same adunit path with multiple ad placements (div ids => adslots), it only depends on how you want to split your inventory

Comment: @rabsom yes I did try your example and it worked. one ad slot with multiple size show ads but once per size. so let's say if I call the same ad slot twice or thrice against same size (300x250) with different multiple <div> id's but only of the such size is working. others are serving blank

Comment: What i was thinking since the order/line item targetted to the ad slot which is calling the same size multiple times using multiple unique <div> is actually having one creative of the same size. Is it the reason that only one creative can serve one size in a ad slot at a moment?

Comment: That's it you figured it out :) If you only have one 300x250 creative running live, Google Ad Manager will only fill one adslot... You need to duplicate the creative or activate new campaigns (or even fill it with adsense when not used by your direct campaigns...)

Comment: @rabsom yes i get it completely now. Thanks